# Spring does not login

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm using the basic form login to secure my application. I set up the security config, web config, a `UserDetailsService` as well as a login template, but however, after typing in the login information, I just get returned to the login form without any error message. Here is mycode:

WebSecurity:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class UserWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth2**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/account", false)
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("remember-me")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .cors().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        }
        
    }
```

The WebConfig important section:

```
    
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("/login");
    }
```

The UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class AccountUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository repo;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOG.info("Called UserDetailsService using username: " + (username != null ? username : "null"));
        Optional<Account> user = repo.findByEmail(username);
        
        if(!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email is invalid");
        }
        
        return user.get();
    }

}
```

EDIT: Apparently the `POST /login` request gets denied with an 403 error, which I don't know why it is appearing.

Comment: and your debug logs are telling you what?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I forgot about the csrf token in the form template

Comment: then thats probably your problem then :D